# Modifying table name in hbm file in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Currently I am stuck in a problem where I have to change table name dynamically in nhibernate config file. The column names are always same only table name changes customer to customer. I had googled this problem and getting some links like

[How to use Nhibernate with variable or dynamic table names like Jan08Tran,Feb08Tran,Mar08Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515985/how-to-use-nhibernate-with-variable-or-dynamic-table-names-like-jan08tran-feb08t)

above one but here I don't know how to implement this using config file.

Please help me to solve out this problem. I am using nhibernate with hbm files and c#.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

use the naming convention:

```
public class MyCustomNamingStrategy : INamingStrategy
{
    public MyCustomNamingStrategy(IDictionary<string, string> properties)
    {
         _properties = properties;
    }

    public string TableName(string tableName)
    {
        tableName = tableName.Replace("[customPart]", _properties["foo"]);
        return DefaultNamingStrategy.Instance.TableName(tableName);
    }

    public string ClassToTableName(string className) { return DefaultNamingStrategy.Instance.ClassToTableName(className); }
    public string PropertyToColumnName(string propertyName) { return DefaultNamingStrategy.Instance.PropertyToColumnName(propertyName); }
    public string ColumnName(string columnName) { return DefaultNamingStrategy.Instance.ColumnName(columnName); }
    public string PropertyToTableName(string classNme, string propertyName) { return DefaultNamingStrategy.Instance.PropertyToTableName(className, propertyName); }
    public string LogicalColumnName(string columnName, string propertyName) { return DefaultNamingStrategy.Instance.LogicalColumnName(columnName, propertyName); }
}
```

and

```
config.SetNamingStrategy(new MyCustomNamingStrategy(config.Properties));
```

then you only need to add this additional property to the hibernate.cfg